# How can I rerender a datatable from a RichFaces' modalPanel?

Tags: richfaces

I'm trying to do it this way, but doesn`t work

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel">
<rich:dataTable id="table">
...
</rich:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>


<rich:modalPanel>
<h:form>
...
...
<a4j:commandButton value="Update dataTable" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="panel" process="..."/>
</h:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `<a4j:outputPanel>` to reRender the panelGroup

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="myOutPanel">
   <h:panelGroup id="panel">
      <rich:dataTable id="table">
      ...
      </rich:dataTable>
   </h:panelGroup>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Modal button...

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Update dataTable" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="myOutPanel" process="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your code to see what `id` the rendered html `<table>` corresponding to your `datatable` has. Or you can use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox for this.

I am suggesting this because of you have included you datatable in a  like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <rich:dataTable id="myId">
    </rich:dataTable>
</form>
```

, the id it will end up with will be `myForm:myId`. So you must either:

- use `reRender="myForm:myId"`
- use the `prependId="true"` on the form to prevent it from appending its own id to the components it includes.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have should work. Try adding a4j:log and check if the id (node) for re-render is found.